# How to create a servicename using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a servicename that should be displayed when I go to "service.msc", powershell script is not able to create.

I tried the following code but its not able to create the service. I am running this as a "Administrator"

```
$serviceName="RSCDsvc"
$serviceDisplayName="BMC BladeLogic Server Automation RSCD Agent"
$serviceDescription="BMC BladeLogic Server Automation Remote System Call Daemon"
$serviceExecutable="RSCDsvc.exe"

LogWrite $bsaLog "Installing service.."


$binaryPath="C:\Program Files\BMC Software\BladeLogic\RSCD\RSCDsvc.exe"

New-Service -name $serviceName -DisplayName $serviceDisplayName -binaryPathName $binaryPath -StartupType Automatic -Description $serviceDescription 

Start-Service -Name $serviceName
Get-Service $serviceName

LogWrite $bsaLog "Service Installed.."
```

I want to see the servicename when I type "services.msc" I should be able to see "RSCDsvc" with display "BMC Bladelogic Server Automation RSCD Agent"

When I run these commands in the powershell prompt individually I get the following error, I could see this service running when I go to taskmanager and go to "Details" tab I could see the service, but not when I go to "services.msc"

```
New-Service : Service 'BMC BladeLogic Server Automation RSCD Agent (RSCDsvc)' cannot be created due to the following error: The 
specified service already exists
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Service -name $serviceName -DisplayName $serviceDisplayName -bina ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (RSCDsvc:String) [New-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotNewService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewServiceCommand
```

Comment: "but its not able to create the service" - please be more descriptive :) does is throw an error (if yes, please post the entire error message)? Does it report success? Do you see _any_ change in the list of services?

Comment: When I run these commands in the powershell prompt individually I get the following error, I could see this service running when I go to taskmanager and go to "Details" tab I could see the service, but not when I go to "services.msc"

New-Service : Service 'BMC BladeLogic Server Automation RSCD Agent (RSCDsvc)' cannot be created due to the following error: The 
specified service already exists
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Have you tried closing `services.msc`, logging out, logging back in (or rebooting) and then relaunching `services.msc`? The Services snap-in is notorious for it's aggressive caching of any interaction against the SCM

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen I restarted and its showing now.